# Input height slightly bigger than link

Tags: html, css

Consider the following example

https://jsfiddle.net/gq5bru8d/1/

```css
 

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

input, a {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: .1rem solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem; }

a {
  text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Input">
<a href="#">Anchor</a>
```

Although both input and anchor tag have the same `font-size`, `line-height`, `padding` and `border`, the input seems to be 1px bigger in height than the anchor tag. Why is that and how can you make it so they both have equal dimensions ?

Comment: Please don't ignore the rules of SO.  Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code in the question itself

Comment: “Having the same font size” doesn’t mean that much, if the font _families_ are different to begin with …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap them in a flex div.

```css
 

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

input, a {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: .1rem solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem; }

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
<input type="text" placeholder="Input">
<a href="#">Anchor</a>
</div>
```

Another solution. Add this style to both elements `font: 13.3333px Arial`

```css
 

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

input, a {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: .1rem solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  font: 13.3333px Arial;

 }

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Input">
<a href="#">Anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using flex by using a wrapper around the input and anchor and set is as

> display:flex

it will make them the same height.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }
  
  .wrapper{display:flex}

input, a {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: .1rem solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem; }

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }
```

```html
  
<div class="wrapper">
<input type="text" placeholder="Input">
<a href="#">Anchor</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons for this:

1. You're not using the same font for both, hence all the relative units are interpreted/calculated to a different value.
2. The input still has a different inner height, which messes with the overall height and, ultimately, the alignment.

```css
 

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input, a {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: .1rem solid black;
  /* Remove the top and bottom padding and replace with line height */
  padding: 0 1rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  /* Set both elements' display property to be inline-block */
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  /* Fix the font family */
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  /* Fix the line height */
  line-height: 3rem;
  /* Set the vertical alignment for both elements */
  vertical-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Input">
<a href="#">Anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to ur `a` and `input` tag

```
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input,
a {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: .1rem solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Input">
<a href="#">Anchor</a>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result.

Comment: The Anchor isn't the same size as the input. It is just in the middle. This hasn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check font family of both input and anchor tag.
Input has some font-style property in your example by default.

Change `%example` to :

```
%example {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: .1rem solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

Here, I only extra added `font-family: Arial;` to css.

Answer (score 0):

To best way to set both element `height` explicitly and make change the like following:

```
%example {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: .1rem solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  height: 50px; // Keyline
  display: inline-block; // without this line height not apply properly
  vertical-align: top; // This line making alignment perfectly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this...

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

input, a {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: .1rem solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
 font: 400 14.3333px Arial;
  line-height: 1rem; }

a {
  text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because your `a` is still inline. Setting it to display as inline-block allows the `line-height` property to shine through. You're also going to want to make sure they're both on the same `vertical-align`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input, a {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: .1rem solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Input">
<a href="#">Anchor</a>
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but the input is still slightly bigger than the anchor.